# Sony Xperia Ray contacts lost after deleting the contents of /data/log

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, contacts, sony-ericsson-xperia-ray

I have an Xperia Ray.

It showed low internal memory. So, I freed up memory by removing the contents of `/data/log/`. Unfortunately, my contacts got deleted. To add to my misery, my laptop crashed. I lost the backup file for contacts.

How do I recover these contacts?

Comment: Did you sync your contacts via Google sync?

Answer (score 0):

If you syncronised yor contacts with google then turn sychro on in settings you will get back all your contacts

```
 or
```

Just log in to your gmail adress and press contacts on the left side pane then show all contacts.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do the following

Make sure no External SD Card is inserted.
- Go to MY FILES
- Touch the SEARCH Button
- Type "vcf" in the search box.
- Start searching.
- Click "vcf" button that appears.
- Follow instructions that appears.

Comment: please don't post separate answers. merge this with your previous answer.